# Stripe payments - passing the basket price into checkout_session in php

Tags: stripe-payments, integration, payment

I am trying to follow the instructions on the stripe site to create a payment system.  I am using PHP.  I have the system working with their default code.  However, I need to pass my own price into create_session.php.  I have tried simple variables and session variables, but whenever I replace the hard coded number with a variable, the checkout button stops working.

You'll see the first line converts a pre-defined session variable into a variable that contains my item price.  That's then called in later as the unit amount.

If I put 2000 into the unit amount instead (i/e/ the hardcoded original value) it works.  So how do I pass a dynamic price across to this?

Here's my code..

```
$price = $_SESSION['stripe_total'];

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('MY_API_GOES_HERE');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://MY_SITE_HERE.co.uk/';


$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'gbp',
      'unit_amount' => $price,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'Prize draw entries from Speedwinners',
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);

echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
```

ADDITION

So I think the issue is how to pass the price variable into the create session file.  I tested by setting $price = 2000; in the file itself and that works fine.

Thus - what I am confused by is how to get that price variable from the page into the file.

The JS that calls the session is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("MY_KEY");
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");

    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("/create-session.php", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

and the code on the checkout page is

```
<section>
      <div class="product">
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Total ticket price</h3>
          <h5>£5.00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the output when you log $price?

Comment: It appears to be nothing.  I've just tested and if I set the variable within the create-session file itself, it works.  So it looks like my problem is passing the variable from the checkout page to the create-session page.

Comment: In the code you posted I'm not seeing where `$_SESSION['stripe_total']` is coming from. Can you also include that?